# LINQ Expression help with Func TEntity,TType

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have a repository method that accepts an order by parameter in the form:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity,string>> orderBy)
```

Now that works fine when trying to sort by a property of type string,

```
var entities = rep.Get(x => x.Name);
```

but what if i want to sort by double or int or any other type.

Doing something like `var entities = rep.Get(x => x.Price);` obviously throws a compile error saying I can't convert double to string.

How can I make this more generic so I can sort by any property in my entity, or at least the properties where the type implements IComparable or something similar?

Comment: Why specify `string` in `Expression<Func<TEntity,string>>` at all? Can't you just put the sorting property as a type parameter as well?

Comment: change string to IComparable?

Comment: @Matt, changing string to IComparable throws a runtime error saying can't convert System.Double to IComparable, only primitive type conversions are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TEntity, TOrderBy>(Expression<Func<TEntity,TOrderBy>> orderBy)
```

Comment: Thanks Hasan, I don't really like the look of having to specify the type, but this certainly works.

Comment: @Chris Are you sure you need to specify the type? Is this CLR 2 or 4?

Comment: @bzlm, this is framework 4. When I remove the type, i get a compile error. Do you have an example of what you're thinking?

Answer (score 2):

**The repository class itself should have a type parameter.** Then you don't need to specify the entity type when accessing the repository members. Like this:

```
public interface IRep<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TOrderBy>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> orderBy
    );
}
```

An example entity class:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

An example repository implementation:

```
public class Rep<TEntity> : IRep<TEntity> { ... }
```

Now you can just consume it like this:

```
var a = new Rep<MyEntity>(); 
var b = a.Get(x => x.Name); // string
var c = a.Get(x => x.Price); // decimal
```

This is how Linq does it. :)

Comment: Very good tips here! +1 I was having similar problems such with this cast exception problem and you was right. You don't need to set the type. But you need to set <TOrderBy> after the method name and set TOrderBy instead of a specific object in the Expression<Func<TEntity, HERE>. This way you can use whatever you want like the example showed here. This must be applied to all through up to the base repository.